# Rename the tables of SQL Server which have dependencies in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one database in which there are lots of tables but the naming convention is not proper.

So I want to rename the tables.

I have checked in google and it is showing the use of **SQL Prompt** but as it is **800+** tables so it will take time to rename the tables one by one and also the dependencies of the tables.

Is there any other way to easily rename the tables and the table dependencies in one single query?

Answer (score 0):

There are system functions that let you list tables and their dependencies. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-dependencies-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for on how to list dependencies. You can also use similar tools to catalogue tables, views etc. This will provide you with a means to generate lists from which you can create scripts but as @MatBaillie says there are no magic shortcuts.

Comment: Thanx peter. I know about those system functions that will give the details of tables and dependencies. But i dont know how i can rename those tables and dependencies in one single script.

Comment: It will not be a single script. And you will need the help of a good text editor with macro facilities. Notepad++ would do the job. AND there are no easy shortcuts.

Comment: ok thanx. Can you please explain me how notepad++ will work for this change??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 EXEC sp_rename 'OldTableName', 'new table name';
```

It will also take care of dependency but it will not change the constrain name.[Click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/rename-tables-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Thanx for the help but it is not changing the table name in the dependent object after applying above logic.

Comment: Dependent object means other function , stored procedure and triggers?

Comment: Yes,it can be function/Stored procedure/View anything.

Comment: So for that if it is one time process then generate the script for sp,function, and trigger and then replace the new table name manually and if do automatically then need c# console app(i prefer u can use any) to read file and replace the word

Answer (score 0):

Not in SQL Script but a power shell alternative can be found here.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3274/auto-rename-sql-server-tables-and-their-references-with-powershell/